# Syntax error in c#

Tags: c#, image

I'm getting a weird syntax error when trying to view an image from the database. It is statement an incorrect syntax error near an operator. I have no idea what is happening as im pretty sure this is all fine until it runs.

> "incorrect syntax near '= "

***View image code***

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        string sql = "Select Image, Image_Name FROM Recipe_Image Where Image_ID =" + imageidTxt.Text + "";
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if(reader.HasRows)
        {
            nameTxt.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[1]);
            if (img == null)
                picImg.Image = null;
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                picImg.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            }
        }
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the empty string `""` at the end of `sql`?

Comment: string sql = "Select Image, Image_Name FROM Recipe_Image Where Image_ID ='" + imageidTxt.Text + "'"; hope it will solve your problem

Comment: The syntax error is in your SQL.  What is the Image_ID column type?  It might require quotes around the value you compare it to if it is varchar.  On the other hand you really should use parameters and specify the type there to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: [Moms will pwn your app](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @David im not entirely stupid. This is my first time getting an image viewing from a database. Once that has been a success i will then include parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: @DonaldBury Parameters solve more problems than just sql injection and it's a good habit to just use them from the get go.

Comment: @DonaldBury what is the `datatype` of the `Image_ID` column in your database?

Comment: @levelonehuman int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This answer has been changed pretty heavily to correct some misinformation.

Previously, this answer suggested using `Convert.ToInt32(x)`. This will *not* directly pass an integer to the database; however, it will happily yell at you (throw an exception) if the value passed in is not an integer.

What *does* happen is that the query string is passed down to `sql` (as a string) and the `sql` parser interprets the value as an `int` based on (little `sql` goblins).

Instead, you should probably be doing something more like this:

```
public void ReadFromDatabase()
{
    int idToFind;

    //check that imageidTxt.Text is an integer
    if  (Int32.TryParse(imageidTxt.Text, out idToFind))
    {
        //we have an integer, so look at the database

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID=" + idToFind;

        //connect to/read from DB
    }
    else
    {
        //fail spectacularly
    }

}
```

This will add (trivial) error checking before you hit the database, and pass in the query as valid syntax.

Note that this answer does not address issues like [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) that have been brought up in comments/answers, and even if it doesn't make much sense to you at the moment, it's very much worth learning about.

Comment: You're assuming that `Image_ID` is a string type column.  It might be numeric and the value of `imageidTxt.Text` is the actual culprit.

Comment: @juharr That is certainly possible, although I don't have much else to go on from the question :) Regardless, the `.Text` property *is* a string, so if nothing else it's a good start at fixing the issue.

Comment: Sure this is certainly the most likely issue, but you can type a number into a text box and maybe then it would "work".  We just don't have enough information to really say what the problem is.

Comment: And the OP just verified that it's an `int`, so this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @juharr I've updated to offer a solution for `int`, and left the original `string` solution in place.

Comment: I've gotten a few downvotes on this answer - anybody care to explain what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: @levelonehuman: I didn't down-vote, but if I were to guess I might suggest that the use of `Convert.ToInt32()` isn't entirely wise in this situation.  If the original problem stemmed from a non-numeric input, then all that would do is result in an exception.

Comment: Well if `imageidTxt.Text` cannot be converted to an int that's going to throw an exception.  And it's just going to convert it back to string to concatenate it to the query.  I have no idea how this could have solved the OP's problem.

Comment: @juharr I'm still kind of new to the world of stackoverflow answering, but I rewrote this answer to address the error you pointed out. Hopefully it was ok to do so!

Comment: @levelonehuman It's not only OK, but encouraged to improve an answer and while best practice is to use parameters your code will technically sanitize the query against SQL injection as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL syntax is invalid, mostly because you're not actually in control of it.  (You have what's called a [SQL Injection Vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)  Instead of executing user-input values as code, treat them as values.  First, define a static query with a parameter placeholder:

```
string sql = "Select Image, Image_Name FROM Recipe_Image Where Image_ID = @Image_ID";
```

Then when you build your `SqlCommand` object, add a parameter for that placeholder:

```
// the query implies that the ID is a number, so make it a number...
int imageId = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(imageidTxt.Text, out imageId)
{
    // entered text wasn't a number, return an error?
}

// then add that number as a parameter
command.Parameters.Add("@Image_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = imageId;
```

This way you've defined a *static* query at design-time, rather than building a *dynamic* (and currently unknown) one at runtime.  So the syntax of the SQL query is known and can be validated as part of the design.

Comment: I have done so but its not actually retrieving the image now.

Comment: @DB: When you debug this, what is the value of `imageId` at runtime?  How have you confirmed that a matching record exists?